# How to find the parent element If I don't know number of elements that is present between the child element and the Parent element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

whats wrong with `FindElement(By.XPath("parent::tr"));` How to find the parent element If I don't know  number of elements that is present between the child element and the Parent element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
 public IWebElement ReturnParentElement(string stringLabel)
    {
        IWebElement actionLabel = DriverManager.IDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("h3")).Single(t => t.Text.Trim().Contains(stringLabel));
        IWebElement parentElement = actionLabel.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
        do
        {
            parentElement = parentElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
        } while (parentElement.TagName != "tr");

        return parentElement;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ancestor::`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) axis to get the parents of an element.
So in this example

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
    <tr class="this">that
        <a>
            <tr class="these">those
                <b>
                    <c />
                </b>
            </tr>
        </a>
    </tr>
</root>
```

to select the first `tr` parent of the element `c` use

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//c/ancestor::tr[1]"));
```

which here results in the `text()`

> those

Comment: It will capture the very first tr tag from the dom. I'm looking for the immediate parent with that tag. Unfortunately none of My tr tags doesn't have any attribute to define it uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this HTML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99
     <a>
        <b></b> 
     </a>
  </price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

You are at node b.

Now **//b** this will select the current node.

```
//b/parent::a  (will select the parent of b which is a)
```

Note that there are multiple ancestor of b node which are price preceded by book and this one preceded by bookstore.

So, `//b/ancestor::price`  will select the **price node** which is ancestor of node **b**.

and , `//b/ancestor::book` will select the **book node** which is ancestor of node **b**.

and , `//b/ancestor::bookstore` will select the **bookstore node** which is ancestor of node **b**.

**UPDATE :**

If you want the immediate parent with that tag , you can use `//b/..`

Note that /.. will give you immediate parent node.
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: @user3386785 : Check out my updated answer in update section or you can refer the above comment too.